# access of files on windows pc from android device, bluetooth?

Tags: android, file-io, bluetooth

I have two folders on a desktop PC running windows 7,  I want to connect an android tablet to that PC by bluetooth and move a file from the android tablet to one of the folders on the windows PC. and get a file from the other folder on the windows PC and copy that to the android tablet.

is it possible to do this without having to run any software on the windows PC.  just only running the android app and using it to access the two folders on the windows PC?

if using bluetooth is not the best way to do this, is there a better way?

i wanted to avoid having to make a java program that i have to run on the PC side.  that means having to install it and make sure that it is running for the file transfer.  would rather just deal with the tablet only.

i am not vary familiar with bluetooth and wanted to get some opinions on using it for this situation, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use bluetooth, from personal experience you need to interact on both the computer and tablet. As a confirmation window for a file transfer appears on either the computer or the tablet.

Wireless can be a better method of transferring files as I believe you can get a file manager app for android so you can easily manage files between desktop and tablet.

Some recommended file managers are available here - http://android.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/top-10-file-managers-for-android/

Hope this helps.