# how to set up a bluetooth connection between windows pc and android device

Tags: android, bluetooth

i have an android device that has an app that i wrote installed on it.  i wanted to send files from it to a windows pc by using bluetooth, and by adding code only to the app on the android phone.

the documentation on the android developers website says that one of the devices must be set up as a server to receive the request for a connection from the client side of the bluetooth connection.

if i try to initiate the connection from the android app side then that side will be the client, and the windows desktop pc will be the server side.  is this possible if i am not writing any code for the windows pc and only using it's built in software that is made to handle the bluetooth hardware?

that would mean that the the included software on the windows pc is set in server mode alwasys waiting for a connection attempt from a bluetooth client, is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit these links. Hope these help

http://www.forward.com.au/pfod/serialBluetoothConnections/index.html
http://blackmarketserver.com/blog/2010/11/23/bluetooth-file-transfer-between-android-2-2-and-windows-7

It is a possible duplicate of this question.
Please have a look

[access of files on windows pc from android device, bluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934922/access-of-files-on-windows-pc-from-android-device-bluetooth)

Comment: You might check out https://github.com/kernl/PC-to-Android-Bluetooth-Example also.  What languages can you program?

Comment: your second link above goes to "page cannot be found" (the link to blackmarketserver item)